# Copying Xcode.app from dmg file to Applications folder takes too long

Tags: xcode, xcode7, osx-yosemite

I don't know what is happening but when I try to open the file `Xcode_7.1.dmg` and copy the `Xcode.app` into the applications folder, there's a point that the progress bar won't move. By the way, I have OS X Yosemite (v10.10.5) installed. Prior to copying, I deleted first the old version of Xcode and emptied Trash.

Answer (score 2):

Gatekeeper takes a while to cryptographic validate the entire app. Just give it the time it needs.

Answer (score 0):

So that progress bar is probably the "preparing to copy xcode.app" and it's just stalling there right?

I had this problem myself. I just kept starting and restarting it (the copying process) and at a point I tried to copy it over to a jump drive. After a few more times starting and restarting it, Xcode began to copy! And the file size was 10.8gb so be warned.

Answer (score 0):

It may also just take a while. I was having issues after an update to Xcode through the app store failed.

It did take a while on that window, but eventually started. I would reckon there are a large amount of files and folder structure that are being mapped at that time. It would be good UX to give some type of indication that something is actually working, though.

Another thing I'd add here--once the copy begins, the time estimate can be misleading. At first, it was indicating that it would take 12 hours to install, but of course, was only a fraction thereof.